# Own command for loading fixtures-data

Tags: symfony, doctrine

There is a `doctrine:fixture:load` command that will load into my `database` certain fake data (a previously created fixture `class`).

I want to create my `own command` ([Console Commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#console-input)), which will only download **selected** classes with fake data. In the documentation everything is clear, but I still can not understand what kind of logic should be that would download the selected fake data.

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        // command name
        ->setName('app:download:fixture');
}


protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->write('There must be logic, but I do not have the faintest idea what it should be');
}
```

I do not ask to do the job for me, but I ask you to share information on this topic or any advice.

Thank you !

Comment: Which bit are you unsure about? Writing symfony commands or writing your own fixtures?

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to do. Do you want to load only some fixtures? What is the input and what are you expecting to be an output.

Comment: @Bananaapple i already have some fixtures classes, which works fine. But i want to load this data by separate command. So i would create command for loading one part of my fixtures and second command will load the rest. I have no idea how can i achieve that

Comment: Well, if you make your fixtures available as service you can call them wherever you want, including from within the command...

Comment: @Bananaapple how can I make my fixture available as service ? Can you show me some examples please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what are you looking for: [How to call commands in command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html).

Unfortunately in a new version of doctrine fixtures [is not possible](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/247) to specify which fixtures to load. Before you could do: `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=path/to/fixture`.

There are some options what you can do here:

1. Use old version of doctrine fixtures that has --fixtures option.
2. You can make a PR or wait [until sombody makes it](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/219).
3. Fixtures command [looks for all services](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/FixturesCompilerPass.php) with tag `doctrine.fixture.orm`. You can play with compiler passes to dynamically 
   load them depending on your needs. Don't have idea how to it technically.
4. Make a command that loads your data by hand.

Comment: Sir, do you have any example how can I load my data by hand ?

Comment: Well it is similar to  [fixture class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#writing-fixtures). 1. you have to [inject](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#accessing-services-from-the-fixtures) EntityManager to your command 2. continue the same way as [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#writing-fixtures)